# How to stop receiving the test support tickets from Salesforce?

Tags: testing, salesforce

We are getting a lot of test support tickets every day in our inbox- this makes it difficult for out support staff to differentiate real support tickets from test tickets. Could we reduce the number of test tickets down to 1 per day?

the email of test support tickets is like follows:

Subject: Case # 00002187: I’m having trouble logging in to xxx app has been assigned to you.

*** NEW CASE ASSIGNMENT NOTIFICATION ***

The following case has been assigned to you. 
Company:
Contact Name:
Case #:  00002177
Subject:  I’m having trouble logging in to xxx app
Description: Hi xxx Support

test message

- xxx xxx

Contact Information and Provider

Patient Name: xxx xxx

Date of Birth: 05/17/2019

Email: testxxx@mail.com (Preferred method of contact)

Phone:

Device Information

User Agent:  {{deviceUserAgent}}

Operating System: iPhone

Browser:

Device: iPhone

OS Version: iOS-12.1

Browser Version:

Is Mobile: False

Is Tablet: False

Is Desktop: False

This email message may contain confidential and/or privileged information. If you are not an addressee or otherwise authorized to receive this message, you should not use, copy, disclose or take any action based on this email or any information contained in the message. If you have received this material in error, please immediately delete this message. Thank you.

To learn more about xxx, visit:  https://www.xxx

Click on the link to access the case:  https://xxx.xxx.salesforce.com/5001G00045qRDTY

Answer (score 0):

The default when sandbox is created is that no mails are sent out (Setup -> Deliverability). If you changed that without doing some "[post sandbox refresh steps](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/955/post-sandbox-refresh-steps)" then it's on you.

You can disable Case Assignment rules in sandboxes after refreshing them. Or change notifications (email alerts etc) to go to some test, IT-controlled mailbox instead of production one?

All emails sent from sandbox should have "Sandbox: " in subject. So maybe just add a rule in MS Exchange server or whatever you use (like you add rules in Outlook) to auto delete them?